# Wordpress won't update with ftp details in wp-config

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site http://briscdisc.co.za/, which I built pretty normally using Wordpress. However, when I tried to update Wordpress or my plugins, it asked my for my ftp details, which it wouldn't accept at first.

I then went and put the details directly into wp-config. However, now when I try to update it just says "unpacking the installation" and doesn't do anything after that, despite leaving it for a long time, so the update never finishes.

Any idea why this is happening?

My hosting is running SQL server 2008 and MySQL 5.x

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permissions issue to me. Normally WP will only prompt you for your FTP connection information when trying to install plugins or a WordPress update if it can't write to /wp-content.

Does the error message say anything more than "unpacking the installation"?

Comment: It's not an error message. It starts to go through the normal installation process: 
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/en_ZA/wordpress-4.7.2.zip…
Unpacking the update…

Then it just stops. There's not even a loading icon in the tab anymore. (I have tried the above solution of adding the FS_METHOD, but same result)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

in `wp-config.php`

If not, just for testing try

```
# chmod 777 -R /path/to/wordpress
# chown www-data -R /path/to/wordpress
# chgrp www-data -R /path/to/wordpress
```

Last two only if you use Apache

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it doesn't seem to have worked :/

Comment: Hi, tbh I'm not sure whether I'm running Apache. The cpanel has a very weird setup and I have a hard time finding anything, but in my database details I don't see anything that says Apache. I tried adding the new solution to wp-config, I only added the first bit of code, and got this error message: The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php

Installation Failed

Answer (score 0):

you are running Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Taken from this site: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/what-server/